# Duplex Service in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-3.0, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a duplex service and i'm using silverlight for the functionality of inserting values and retrieving values.The first thing i want to know is:

when i add a new endpoint for example wsdualhttpbinding,then my service doesn't work.It doesn't give any error but it neither retrieves nor inserts the values.

Second thing is if any one can provide me the code for implementing Duplex Service and WsDualHttpBinding.Duplex for silverlight and WsDualHttpBinding for asp.net

Comment: No accepted answers and 1 measly vote.  Not playing the game very nicely, are we?  You might want to try giving back via votes and accepted answers to the people who are helping you or they might stop.

Comment: ...FYI, the FAQ explains how SO works in great detail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,i would be doing what u have told

Answer (score 1):

For information on duplex binding there is a ton of information only a search away: http://www.liquidjelly.co.uk/supersearch/?q=silverlight%20duplex%20binding&lang=en-GB

Remember that HTTP binding for Silvelight [is limited](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/11/WPF-Silverlight).

Good luck. (Remember what tvanfosson has suggested - you can do this historically too)

Comment: but i'm not able to find any sample for duplex and wsdualhttpbinding,there is information provided on what are these but not the sample